# Implement search in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, character-encoding

Everyone know how to implement search in page with codeiginter.

One issue is that my keyword, for example "Șaweqă" has diacritisc. How to search into database table with this keyword.

Simple `$this->db->like($keyword);` return database error.

My database character encoding is set to `utf8-general-ci` and the table where i do search has rows with `utf8_romanian_ci` encoding.

Comment: What is the database error?

Comment: Are you connecting with utf8?  What is the table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)?  Are the bytes in the client encoded utf8?  Or latin1?

Comment: @Rick James How to verify that all is right or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` *should* look one of these ways:

```
the_column ... CHARACTER SET utf8,   -- or utf8mb4
```

or, if not specified on `the_column`, then

```
CREATE TABLE ... (...) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;  -- or utf8mb4
```

To check that `Șaweqă` was *stored* (via `INSERT`, etc) correctly as utf8, do something like `SELECT HEX(col)...`.  You should get `C898 61 77 65 71 C483` for `Șaweqă`.  (I added spaces to distinguish the characters.)

To check that it is fetched (via `SELECT`, etc) correctly, look at the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try allowing special character in the CI config file :

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:@_\-ä';
```

And if you are using `GET` method, try to `urldecode()` the keyword :

```
$keyword = urldecode($keyword);
```

Comment: `_GET` has already decoded the incoming data.  The only reason to use `urldecode` is if the source called `urlencode` (explicitly or implicitly) twice.